# Giving a multiselect combox a default (set of) value(s)

Tags: ms-access

I am currently using multiselect comboboxes to specify filters for a query (that will go on to generate a report).

I have it all working fine, apart from the fact I would like to specify default values to each of these comboboxes when the form is loaded.

It seems like using the builtin default box in the property panel doesn't accept multiple values (or rather I don't know how to give it multiple values)

I have tried selecting the values I want at runtime using the `Selected` property of the control:

```
For i = 0 To Me.MyComboBox.ListCount - 1
    Me.MyComboBox.Selected(i) = True
    Debug.Print Me.MyComboBox.Selected(i)      'Returns false
Next i
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work. It doesn't give an error or anything, but setting it just doesn't seem to change the value.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? I would essentially like to go on to have an "All" button next to each combobox that selects all the values in the combobox, so preferably a VBA approach to the problem would benefit me the most.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following before setting the `Selected` property:

```
MyCombobox.SetFocus
MyCombobox.ListIndex = 0
```

Comment: It is bound yes, so far the only way I've found to have it as a multiselect box is to bind it to a multiselect field in a table. The table is definitely not read only, I can update it if I select the entries manually. Just doing it through VBA doesn't work.

Comment: Is the underlying query updateable? Can you edit another bound control on the same form? If not, that may be your problem.

Comment: There is no underlying query (that I have defined). I have set the form source to be the table. The for is entirely functional, I can update the all fields, change any records (and have the saved). The only problem is setting the values through VBA.

Comment: I wonder if it is a bug in Access. Are you up to date with your Service Packs?

Comment: I am completely up to date. Can I ask if you are experiencing the same problem? If it is an access problem I will move on and try and find another way presenting it, otherwise I can focus on trying to fix my particular setup.

Comment: It is not a bug. I checked through code of mine and found that you need to have the control in focus. See my edited answer above.

Comment: I apologise for this incredibly late reply, I seem to have missed the notification all together for the most recent comment. Set focus and Listindex did the trick! Unfortunately I had further troubles getting anything back from ItemData apart from Null values so I couldn't use it how I wanted, but it did help, thank you!